# Error popup from Code::Blocks when trying to do C development

Tags: c, codeblocks

Why do get this error popup:

> wxWidgets Debug Alert
>
> A debugger check in this application is failed
>
> ....\include\wx/font.h(282):assert "numweight"....

I used to get this error when I open `codeblocks` for C programming.  I also get it when I create a new project and when I click setting for font editing. I see this same error in other questions but the heading is

[image: click here to view the error image]

Comment: Not _asset_, it's ___assert___, which is a runtime check made in a debug-mode build of your program.  The author of that code has made a claim that `numWeight > 0` should be true in order for the code to work correctly and left a handy check called an _assertion_.  And yet, somehow you've encountered a situation where that assertion is not true.  It may indicate that you're using the API incorrectly, or it could indicate a shortcoming in that library, or you may have a bug.

Comment: @Wyck so Will i  get any problem in future while coding because of this error??